# Don't work controller/bones on rigs blender

Tags: animation, bones

Sorry, English is not my native language. I've run into a problem where "options" are not used in public access in Riga. The object was easily spoiled in the program, all the "parameters" fly around the object/character, but I can't twist or move them to somehow animate the object. The program completely highlights all the "parameters", but does not allow them to be adjusted and moved individually. I am new to Blender. Hope it helps me. Thank you[image]

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you are referring to as “parameters” are the bones of the Armature. You need to go into Pose mode to be able to move/rotate each bone individually to deform the mesh. Pose mode is in the same pull-down menu as Object mode and Edit mode.

I recommend you read [the Blender Manual section on Armatures](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/armatures/index.html), but change the language as needed, bottom left.